# automatic array list swift

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift

```
import UIKit
var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "f1"),UIImage(named: "f2"),UIImage(named: "f3"),UIImage(named: "f4")]
class Interest
{
    // MARK: - Public API
    var title = ""
    var featuredImage: UIImage
    var color: UIColor


    init(title: String, featuredImage: UIImage, color: UIColor)
    {
        self.title = title
        self.featuredImage = featuredImage
        self.color = color
    }

    // MARK: - Private
    // dummy data
    static func fetchInterests() -> [Interest]
    {
        return [
            Interest(title: "Travelling Around the World", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f1")!, color: UIColor(red: 63/255.0, green: 71/255.0, blue: 80/255.0, alpha: 0.8)),
            Interest(title: "Cafe with Best Friends", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f2")!, color: UIColor(red: 240/255.0, green: 133/255.0, blue: 91/255.0, alpha: 0.8)),
            Interest(title: "Study Personal Development Books and Courses", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f3")!, color: UIColor(red: 105/255.0, green: 80/255.0, blue: 227/255.0, alpha: 0.8)),
            Interest(title: "Build Amazing iOS Apps", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f4")!, color: UIColor(red: 102/255.0, green: 102/255.0, blue: 102/255.0, alpha: 0.8)),
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to use array after return statement but I can not , I want to make the example similar

```
return [
            Interest(title: "Travelling Around the World", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "imageArray[i]")!, color: UIColor(red: 63/255.0, green: 71/255.0, blue: 80/255.0, alpha: 0.8)),

        ]
```

Automatically add how many elements are in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the images you stored in the array `imageArray` inside your return statement you’d have to reference the array like this:

```
Interest(title: “Title”, featuredImage: imageArray[i], ....
```

Without the quotation marks. The way you do it now, swift will look for an Image file that’s literally called “imageArray[i]”, which of course doesn’t exist.

To generate Intersts from all images you’d have to iterate over the `imageArray` and generate your return array dynamically before returning it.

Hope this helps